# Please help me identify 12 V LED lights driver

Tags: led, identification, mosfet-driver, led-driver

[image]

I have a set of eagle lights LEDs for motorcycle and the chip that has BOF2801 is the one burnt up. And as far as I can find out I believe it’s an led driver of some sort but can’t find anything definitive or anything compatible to where I can swap it out myself here and salvage these lights.

I can send more pics if need be. And I’m just a guy who try’s to fix my stuff when it breaks. So forgive me if my vocabulary is incorrect I’m no computer engineer. Also it might also be a MOSFET type of driver. It's for LED lights or a motorcycle so it’s 12 V. There are only three LED bulbs, they’re not dimmable they’re constant. I don’t know if it’s a constant voltage drive constant current drive.

I did find a part called HV 9910C it says a universal high brightness, LED driver.

Comment: It might be equivalent to a UCC2801: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc2800-ep.pdf?ts=1691763560311&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F